# cortana removal from screen on PC

Tags: cortana

I can't remove Cortana from the bottom of my PC. I am not sure how it got there. It takes up too much of my screen. I just want to hide it. Not computer savy. I tried some of the suggestions but no help. does anyone have any help

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the task bar at the bottom of your screen, this will bring up a menu - from here, near the top you should see the word "Cortana" or "Search". In the resulting sub menu there is a "Hide" option (there is also the option to show just the icon, which still gives quick access to it, if you find Cortana as useful as I do) :)

Comment: Make sure you click on the "empty" space